# inputmask numeric with two decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to transform my normal input field unto a numeric input with two decimal places using the great plugin called "inputmask" by awesome "RobinHerbots", below snippet is what I tried but sadly and unfortunately its not working, any ideas, help please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.decimal').inputmask('decimal', { rightAlign: false, digits: 2, placeholder: "0" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="decimal form-control" />
```

Comment: i just played around with it i dont know if this will help but give it a look `$('.decimal').inputmask({
            mask: "*[.**]",
            greedy: false,
            definitions: {
                '*': {
                    validator: "[0-9]"
                }
            }
    });`

Comment: @guradio: cool, but how to extend the digits, currently its like "6.55" and I want like this "6.555555555 and so on" any ideas?

Comment: were you able to make it?i cant a way to make many decimals you can increase `***` to achieve what you want but i think it is not a good idea you need a dynamic approach on that which i havent got any solution to

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.decimal').inputmask({ mask: "99.99"}) // As you requested
```

OR

```
$('.decimal').inputmask({ mask: "99.9{2}"}) //Same as the first one, {2} mean preceding char count MUST be 2
```

OR

```
$('.decimal').inputmask({ mask: "(99)|(99.9{1,2})"}) //We use optional here so user can enter 99 or 99.9 or 99.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/Ln375fmz/

```js
$('.decimal').inputmask({
            mask: "9{0,20}Z9{2}",
            definitions: {
                "Z": {
                    validator: "[.]",
                }
            },
            clearIncomplete: true,
            autoUnmask: true,
            placeholder: "",
        });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="money">
```